# Get all posts by multiple categories

Tags: wordpress

I want to get all posts by specifying multiple categories from drop-down list. In
`pre_get_posts` i want to modify the query to search by selected categories(more than one).

```
$taxquery = ($taxquery, array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'cat',
            'field'  => 'id',
            'terms'  => array('1','2'),
            'operator'=> 'IN'
            ));          
$query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
```

But when I execute this code, non of the posts are shown(I am sure that there is posts in at least one of that two categories)
Maybe there is better way for searching by more than one category by using **`OR`** when search by the first,second... categories.
Any directions would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging I finally found the solution...

There was several mistakes as: Ids needs to be Integers in terms array, `taxonomy` needs to be `'category'` not `'cat'`, in my case the relation needs to be OR as I want to search by multiple categories and **by other custom field**, and at least one category needs to be meet...

Here is example of the code:

```
$taxquery =  array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                    'field'  => 'id',
                    'terms'  => array(1,2,3),
                    'operator'=> 'IN'
                  )); 
        $query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `term_id`, instead `id`, and then you should add additional `array` to your tax_query, because you nay have more than one. So your code will look like this:

```
$category_ids = array(1,2);
$query->set( 'category__in', $category_ids );
```

Comment: still the same, there is no results... are you sure that this is the proper way?

Comment: Wait is the `cat` is a custom taxonomy or default wordpress category?

Comment: Then you should use the `category__in`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: i have set just this `$query->set( 'category__in', array('1') );` for showing uncategorized posts (hard-coded) and still noting :/

Comment: Can you please share your $wp_query? And the entire `pre_get_posts` function/

Comment: the function is just the code `$query->set( 'category__in', array('1') );` hardcoded as I said. I think there is problem with the AND and OR values.

Comment: Ahhhh, you should use integers instead strings, so `array('1')` will become `array(1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128293/discussion-between-stanimir-stoyanov-and-rabne).